# SHAP: XGBoost and LightGBM difference in shap_values calculation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shap

I have this code in visual studio code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xgboost as xgb 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold, cross_validate, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, ConfusionMatrixDisplay, accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv("./mydataset.csv")
target=df.pop('target')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=22)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=22)

xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(eval_metric='mlogloss',use_label_encoder =False)
xgb_fitted = xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xgb_fitted)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test, plot_type="bar")
```

when I run this code, I am getting this error:

```
Summary plots need a matrix of shap_values, not a vector.
```

on the `shap.summary_plot` line.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

The above code is based on this code sample: https://github.com/slundberg/shap.

the dataset is as follow:

```
Cat1,Cat2,Age,Cat3,Cat4,target
0,0,18,1,0,1
0,0,17,1,0,1
0,0,15,1,1,1
0,0,15,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,0,17,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,1,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,0,15,1,0,1
0,0,15,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,1,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,1,17,1,0,0
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,0,15,0,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
```

Please note that actual data has 700 rows, but I copied a small portion of it just to show how data is look like.

## Edit 1

The main reason for this question is to understand how the code should be changed when using different classifiers.

I had originally a sample code with lgmb which worked but when I changed it to xgboost, It generate error on summary plot.

To show what I mean, I developed the following sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import shap
import lightgbm as lgb
import xgboost as xgb 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("./mydataset.csv")
target=df.pop('target')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=22)

# select one of the two models
model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
#model = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
model_fitted = model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model_fitted)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test, plot_type="bar")
```

if I use LGBM model, it works well and if I use XGBoost, it failed. What is the difference and how should I change the code that XGBoost behave similarly to LGBM and application works.

Comment: What is `mydataset.csv`?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov The file contains a sample dataset with some features and a target.  I don't believe the problem is with the dataset.

Comment: @mans could you provide some sample data? this error might be happening cause `shap_values` could be (m, n) dimension and `shap_values[1]` a 1 dimensional vector.

Comment: @mans I am familiar with the DS flow. The question was "show your data", or provide a [reprex]. A  side note: `target=df['target']` should read `target=df.pop['target']`. Show us your data please.

Comment: @MiguelTrejo, please find the requested information in the edited question. It should be noted that if I use shap.plot.bar(), then I don't have any problem.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Thanks for your comment, I updated the code and also add the requested information. If you need any other information, let me know.

Comment: @mans yes, bar plot accepts single sample `If a single sample is passed then we plot the SHAP values as a bar chart.`

Answer (score 0):

Notice that with `summary_plot()` you want to visualize which features in general are more important to the model, so it requires a matrix

> For single output explanations this is a matrix of SHAP values (# samples x # features).

the result from `shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)` is a matrix of shape `(n_samples, 5)` (columns in sample data).

When you take the first sample `shap_values[0]` is a vector that explains first prediction feature contributions, that's why `Summary plots need a matrix of shap_values, not a vector.` raises.

If you want to visualize individual predictions `shap_values[0]` you could use a [force_plot](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.plots.force.html?highlight=force_plot)

```
shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0])
```

[image]

### EDIT

The difference between the outputs of the two models is due to how the `out` result is calculated. Checking the source code for `lightgbm` calculation once the variable `phi` is calculated, it [concatenates the values](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L352) in the following way

```
phi = np.concatenate((0-phi, phi), axis=-1)
```

generating an array of shape `(n_samples, (n_features+1)*2)`.

This shape is different from `X_test`, that is, `phi.shape[1] != X.shape[1] + 1` (NB: `phi.shape[1] == 2 * (X.shape[1] + 1)`), so it [reshapes it](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L355) two a three dimensional array

```
phi = phi.reshape(X.shape[0], phi.shape[1]//(X.shape[1]+1), X.shape[1]+1)
```

Finally the output is a [list of length two](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L372)

```
out = [phi[:, i, :-1] for i in range(phi.shape[1])]
out
>>>
[array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...  
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])]
```

See examples below to see how `out` calculation differs.

### Example with `LightGBM`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shap
import lightgbm as lgb
import xgboost as xgb 
import shap.explainers as explainers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
target=df.pop('target')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, target, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

model = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
model_fitted = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model_fitted)

# Calculate phi from https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L347
tree_limit = -1 if explainer.model.tree_limit is None else explainer.model.tree_limit
phi = explainer.model.original_model.predict(X_test, num_iteration=tree_limit, pred_contrib=True)

# Objective is binary: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L349
if explainer.model.original_model.params['objective'] == 'binary':
    phi = np.concatenate((0-phi, phi), axis=-1)

# Phi shape is different from X_test:
if phi.shape[1] != X_test.shape[1] + 1:
    phi = phi.reshape(X_test.shape[0], phi.shape[1]//(X_test.shape[1]+1), X_test.shape[1]+1)

# Return out: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L370
expected_value = [phi[0, i, -1] for i in range(phi.shape[1])]
out = [phi[:, i, :-1] for i in range(phi.shape[1])]
expected_value
>>> [-0.8109302162163288, 0.8109302162163288]
out
>>> 
[array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])]
```

### Example with XGBoost

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shap
import lightgbm as lgb
import xgboost as xgb 
import shap.explainers as explainers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
target=df.pop('target')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, target, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model_fitted = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model_fitted)

# Transform data to DMatrix: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L326
if not isinstance(X_test, xgb.core.DMatrix):
    X_test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test)

tree_limit = explainer.model.tree_limit

# Calculate phi: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L331
phi = explainer.model.original_model.predict(
    X_test, ntree_limit=tree_limit, pred_contribs=True,
    approx_contribs=False, validate_features=False
)

# Model output is "raw": https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L339
model_output_vals = explainer.model.original_model.predict(
    X_test, ntree_limit=tree_limit, output_margin=True,
    validate_features=False
)
model_output_vals
>>> array([-0.11323176, -0.11323176,  0.5436669 ,  0.87637275,  1.5332711 ,
       -0.11323176,  1.5332711 ,  0.5436669 ,  1.5332711 ,  0.5436669 ,
        0.87637275,  0.87637275, -0.11323176,  0.5436669 ], dtype=float32)

# Return out: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L374
expected_value_ = phi[0, -1]
expected_value_
>>> 0.817982
out_ = phi[:, :-1]
out_
>>>
array([[ 0.        , -0.35038763, -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.35038763, -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.3065111 , -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.35038763,  0.4087782 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.3065111 ,  0.4087782 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.35038763, -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.3065111 ,  0.4087782 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.3065111 , -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.3065111 ,  0.4087782 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.3065111 , -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.35038763,  0.4087782 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.35038763,  0.4087782 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.35038763, -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.3065111 , -0.5808259 ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Comment: please see the updated question. Why does the same code work with LGBM and not XGBoost?

Comment: @mans checking the source code, there's a difference in how the result is calculated for `lightgbm` and `xgboost`, see updated answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have copied the data from the question above, the following will do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import (
    train_test_split,
    StratifiedKFold,
    cross_validate,
    cross_val_score,
)
from sklearn.metrics import (
    classification_report,
    ConfusionMatrixDisplay,
    accuracy_score,
)

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",")

target = df.pop("target")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
    X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)


xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(eval_metric="mlogloss", use_label_encoder=False)
xgb_fitted = xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xgb_fitted)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
# shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, plot_type="bar")
```

[image]

The code you pasted assumes 2 ["identical"] arrays of shap values per class "0" and "1". Something has changed in the way `explainer.shap_values` calculates SHAP values for `XGBoost` since it was printed. So, now supplying `shap_values` (without class index) is just enough.

Comment: Thanks, but what does the plot show? is it for class 0 or 1? If I use the same plotting command for xgboost, I am getting a different type of plot that explains each class.

Comment: These are for class "1". Assuming you enter the same code as I we should have identical plots.

Comment: How can I get information for class 0?

Comment: They are identical up to a sign: what increases chances of being 1 decrease 0 by the same amount (due to additivity I guess).

Comment: @mans Does your code work now?

Comment: Yes, it is working, but also see the updated question.

Comment: @mans I believe the original question is answered as it used to be, the code is working now and explained why. If you wish more you may think about opening another one.